# Default username and password in Worklight Application Center

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-appcenter

Our team has installed the IBM Worklight server 6.2 in our server machine. The installation was successful and no errors occurred.

Though, when we tried to go to the Worklight Application center (**localhost:8080/appcenterconsole/j_security_check**). We have tried using the usual "admin" for username and password and tried the username and password we inputted during the installation, but we still could not log in to the console.

Is there another default username and password? Or is there a way we could find/change the username and password?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The info center indicates that you need [explicitly to set up user/password entries](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/appcenter/t_configuring_websphere_applicat1.html) for App Center.

Check in your server.xml if this has been done, and if so you'll see entries like this:

```
<security-role name="appcenteradmin">
  <group name="appcenteradmingroup"/>
</security-role>
<security-role name="appcenteruser">
  <group name="appcenterusergroup"/>
</security-role>


<basicRegistry id="appcenter">
  <user name="admin" password="admin"/>
  <user name="guest" password="guest"/>
  <user name="demo" password="demo"/>
  <group name="appcenterusergroup">
        <member name="guest" />
        <member name=" demo" />
  </group>
  <group name="appcenteradmingroup">
        <member name="admin" id=”admin"/>
  </group>
</basicRegistry>
```

If you don't have them then this explains why admin/admin is not working for you.

Comment: may I know where the server.xml file is located? I tried searching in IBM directory but we couldn't find it.

Comment: For additional information, we are using Apache Tomcat and MySQL for our IBM Worklight Server.

Comment: solved my question with this [link](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/appcenter/t_configuring_apache_tomcat.html). Thank you!